# Error with dynamic data to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, serialization, append

I have an error with my script listed below. I have no idea where I am going wrong I’ve tried multiple variations and ways to code it and I still come out with nothing.

As you can tell I have a custom generated section for a user to enter in data. Basically when they click it adds another section. Then I want to convert that data into an array on click. It seems to work for my user information (the top section) but for some reason it won’t print the sub array within the for loop that I have for each product section.

```js
var id = 0;
$('#addbutton').click(function() {
  id++;
  var large = '<div class="contentprint" id="section[' + id + ']"><h2>Product:' + id + '</h2>' +
    '<p class="form-check has-success"><label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" style="user-select: none" class="form-check-input btn btn-success" id="logo' + id + '" value="yes">Custom Logo</label></p><p style="font-size: 10px; margin: 0px">*Please provide in high resolution .png format(upon confirmation of quote)</p><p style="font-size: 10px; margin: 0px">*$50 set up fee for new logos on orders up to 10 plates</p>' +
    '<input id="quantity' + id + '" style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" type="number" class="form-control quanty" placeholder="Enter Quantity">' +
    '<select  id="orientation"' + id + '" style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" class="ori" ><option disabled selected value> -- Orientation --</option> <option value="clipsal_2000_series">Horizontal</option><option value="clipsal_2000_series">Vertical</option></select>' +
    '<select class="plate" id="plate"' + id + '" style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" ><option disabled selected value> -- Wall Plate --</option><option value="clipsal_2000_series">Clipsal 2000 series</option><option value="clipsal_classic_2000_series">Clipsal classic 200 series</option><option value="clipsal_standard_31_series">Clipsal standard 31 series</option><option value="other">Other(list in comments)</option></select>' +
    '<select class="color" id="colour"' + id + '" style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" > <option disabled selected value> -- Colour --</option> <option value="white">White</option> <option value="black">Black</option> <option value="other">Other(list in comments)</option></select>' +
    '<p style="margin-top:10px; width:100%">Choose your connections</p>' +
    ' <select class="1consel" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="1connection' + id + '"><option disabled selected value> -- Connection 1 --</option> <option> HDMI(Tail)</option><option>VGA(Tail)</option><option>Displayport Tail Female to Female</option> <option>FType(TV) 3Ghz Female to Female</option><option>Optical(Tos Link)</option> <option>Data(RJ45 Cat6 Ethernet [Cat5e compatible])</option><option>BNC(Video)</option><option>DVI (Pass through adapter)</option><option>RS232(DB9)(Pass through adapter)</option><option>SVideo(Pass through adapter)</option><optgroup label="USB"><option>A Female to A Female</option> <option>B Female to A Female</option> <option> USB A Female to A Male</option> <option> USB B Male to A Female</option><option>USB B Female to B Male</option> <option>USB Active Extender A Female to A Female</option> </optgroup>  <optgroup label="XLR"><option>Male Gen 3</option><option>Male Gen 4</option><option>Male Gen 5</option><option>Female Gen 3</option><option>Female Gen 4</option><option>Female Gen 5</option></optgroup><optgroup label="RCA Pass though adapters"><option>Audio(Red &amp; White)</option> <option>Composite video(Yellow)</option><option>AV COmbined(RWY)</option></optgroup><option>Component(All RCA RGB) All RCA Pass Throughs</option></select>' +
    ' <select class="2consel" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="2connection' + id + '"><option disabled selected value> -- Connection 2 --</option> <option> HDMI(Tail)</option><option>VGA(Tail)</option><option>Displayport Tail Female to Female</option> <option>FType(TV) 3Ghz Female to Female</option><option>Optical(Tos Link)</option> <option>Data(RJ45 Cat6 Ethernet [Cat5e compatible])</option><option>BNC(Video)</option><option>DVI (Pass through adapter)</option><option>RS232(DB9)(Pass through adapter)</option><option>SVideo(Pass through adapter)</option> <optgroup label="USB"><option>A Female to A Female</option> <option>B Female to A Female</option> <option> USB A Female to A Male</option> <option> USB B Male to A Female</option><option>USB B Female to B Male</option> <option>USB Active Extender A Female to A Female</option> </optgroup>  <optgroup label="XLR"><option>Male Gen 3</option><option>Male Gen 4</option><option>Male Gen 5</option><option>Female Gen 3</option><option>Female Gen 4</option><option>Female Gen 5</option></optgroup><optgroup label="RCA Pass though adapters"><option>Audio(Red &amp; White)</option> <option>Composite video(Yellow)</option><option>AV COmbined(RWY)</option></optgroup><option>Component(All RCA RGB) All RCA Pass Throughs</option></select>' +
    ' <input class="1consellog" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="1wordconnection' + id + '" placeholder="Connection 1 Custom Label(max 15 chars)" type="text" />' +
    ' <input class="2consellog" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="2wordconnection' + id + '" placeholder="Connection 2 Custom Label(max 15 chars)" type="text" />' +
    ' <select class="3consel" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="3connection' + id + '"><option disabled selected value> -- Connection 3 --</option><option> HDMI(Tail)</option><option>VGA(Tail)</option><option>Displayport Tail Female to Female</option> <option>FType(TV) 3Ghz Female to Female</option><option>Optical(Tos Link)</option> <option>Data(RJ45 Cat6 Ethernet [Cat5e compatible])</option><option>BNC(Video)</option><option>DVI (Pass through adapter)</option><option>RS232(DB9)(Pass through adapter)</option><option>SVideo(Pass through adapter)</option>  <optgroup label="USB"><option>A Female to A Female</option> <option>B Female to A Female</option> <option> USB A Female to A Male</option> <option> USB B Male to A Female</option><option>USB B Female to B Male</option> <option>USB Active Extender A Female to A Female</option> </optgroup> <optgroup label="XLR"><option>Male Gen 3</option><option>Male Gen 4</option><option>Male Gen 5</option><option>Female Gen 3</option><option>Female Gen 4</option><option>Female Gen 5</option></optgroup><optgroup label="RCA Pass though adapters"><option>Audio(Red &amp; White)</option> <option>Composite video(Yellow)</option><option>AV COmbined(RWY)</option></optgroup><option>Component(All RCA RGB) All RCA Pass Throughs</option></select>' +
    ' <select class="4consel" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="4connection' + id + '"><option disabled selected value> -- Connection 4 --</option><option> HDMI(Tail)</option><option>VGA(Tail)</option><option>Displayport Tail Female to Female</option> <option>FType(TV) 3Ghz Female to Female</option><option>Optical(Tos Link)</option> <option>Data(RJ45 Cat6 Ethernet [Cat5e compatible])</option><option>BNC(Video)</option><option>DVI (Pass through adapter)</option><option>RS232(DB9)(Pass through adapter)</option><option>SVideo(Pass through adapter)</option> <optgroup label="USB"><option>A Female to A Female</option> <option>B Female to A Female</option> <option> USB A Female to A Male</option> <option> USB B Male to A Female</option><option>USB B Female to B Male</option> <option>USB Active Extender A Female to A Female</option> </optgroup> <optgroup label="XLR"><option>Male Gen 3</option><option>Male Gen 4</option><option>Male Gen 5</option><option>Female Gen 3</option><option>Female Gen 4</option><option>Female Gen 5</option></optgroup><optgroup label="RCA Pass though adapters"><option>Audio(Red &amp; White)</option> <option>Composite video(Yellow)</option><option>AV COmbined(RWY)</option></optgroup><option>Component(All RCA RGB) All RCA Pass Throughs</option></select>' +
    ' <input class="3consellog" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="3wordconnection' + id + '" placeholder="Connection 3 Custom Label(max 15 chars)" type="text" />' +
    ' <input class="4consellog" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="4wordconnection' + id + '" placeholder="Connection 4 Custom Label(max 15 chars)" type="text" />' +
    ' <select class="5consel" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="5connection' + id + '"><option disabled selected value> -- Connection 5 --</option><option> HDMI(Tail)</option><option>VGA(Tail)</option><option>Displayport Tail Female to Female</option> <option>FType(TV) 3Ghz Female to Female</option><option>Optical(Tos Link)</option> <option>Data(RJ45 Cat6 Ethernet [Cat5e compatible])</option><option>BNC(Video)</option><option>DVI (Pass through adapter)</option><option>RS232(DB9)(Pass through adapter)</option><option>SVideo(Pass through adapter)</option> <optgroup label="USB"><option>A Female to A Female</option> <option>B Female to A Female</option> <option> USB A Female to A Male</option> <option> USB B Male to A Female</option><option>USB B Female to B Male</option> <option>USB Active Extender A Female to A Female</option> </optgroup> <optgroup label="XLR"> <option>Male Gen 3</option><option>Male Gen 4</option><option>Male Gen 5</option><option>Female Gen 3</option><option>Female Gen 4</option><option>Female Gen 5</option></optgroup><optgroup label="RCA Pass though adapters"><option>Audio(Red &amp; White)</option> <option>Composite video(Yellow)</option><option>AV COmbined(RWY)</option></optgroup><option>Component(All RCA RGB) All RCA Pass Throughs</option></select>' +
    ' <select class="6consel" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="6connection' + id + '"><option disabled selected value> -- Connection 6 --</option><option> HDMI(Tail)</option><option>VGA(Tail)</option><option>Displayport Tail Female to Female</option> <option>FType(TV) 3Ghz Female to Female</option><option>Optical(Tos Link)</option> <option>Data(RJ45 Cat6 Ethernet [Cat5e compatible])</option><option>BNC(Video)</option><option>DVI (Pass through adapter)</option><option>RS232(DB9)(Pass through adapter)</option><option>SVideo(Pass through adapter)</option> <optgroup label="USB"><option>A Female to A Female</option> <option>B Female to A Female</option> <option> USB A Female to A Male</option> <option> USB B Male to A Female</option><option>USB B Female to B Male</option> <option>USB Active Extender A Female to A Female</option> </optgroup> <optgroup label="XLR"> <option>Male Gen 3</option><option>Male Gen 4</option><option>Male Gen 5</option><option>Female Gen 3</option><option>Female Gen 4</option><option>Female Gen 5</option></optgroup><optgroup label="RCA Pass though adapters"><option>Audio(Red &amp; White)</option> <option>Composite video(Yellow)</option><option>AV COmbined(RWY)</option></optgroup><option>Component(All RCA RGB) All RCA Pass Throughs</option></select>' +
    ' <input class="5consellog" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="5wordconnection' + id + '" placeholder="Connection 5 Custom Label(max 15 chars)" type="text" />' +
    ' <input class="6consellog" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="6wordconnection' + id + '" placeholder="Connection 6 Custom Label(max 15 chars)" type="text" />' +
    '<textarea name="specialinstructions"' + id + '" style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" class="form-control special" rows="3" placeholder="Special Instructions"></textarea>' +
    '<br><hr><br></div>';

  $('div.addsection').append(large);
  event.preventDefault();
});
$('#removeprod').on('click', function() {
  $('.contentprint').remove();
});
$('#serialize').click(function() {
  var entereddata = [];
  var products = [];

  var i;
  //id is the count of the sections
  for (i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {

    var indivproduct = [];
    //dont forget logo
    indivproduct.push([$("input#quantity" + i).val(), $("input#orientation" + i).val(), $("input#plate" + i).val(), $("input#colour" + i).val(), $("input#1connection" + i).val(), $("input#1wordconnection" + i).val(), $("input#2connection" + i).val(), $("input#2wordconnection" + i).val(), $("input#3connection" + i).val(), $("input#3wordconnection" + i).val(), $("input#4connection" + i).val(), $("input#4wordconnection" + i).val(), $("input#5connection" + i).val(), $("input#5wordconnection" + i).val(), $("input#6connection" + i).val(), $("input#6wordconnection" + i).val(), $("input#specialinstructions" + i).val()]);

    products.push(indivproduct);

  };

  entereddata.push([$("input#contactname").val(), $("input#companyname").val(), $("input#address").val(), $("input#contactnumber").val(), $("input#email").val(), $("input#requiredby").val(), products]);
  alert(JSON.stringify(entereddata));

  /*send json data to file
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: {mydata: JSON.stringify(entereddata)},
      url: "index.php",
      success: function(data){
      }
  });
  */
});
```

```html
<form align="center" method="post" action="">
  <!--action=kidigital.php-->
  <div align="center">
    <input style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" type="text" class="form-control details" id="contactname" name="Contactname" placeholder="Contact Name">
    <input style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" type="text" class="form-control details" id="companyname" name="Companyname" placeholder="Company Name">
    <input style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" type="text" class="form-control details" id="address" name="Address" placeholder="Address">
    <input style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" type="number" class="form-control details" id="contactnumber" name="Contactnumber" placeholder="Contact Number">
    <input style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" type="email" class="form-control details" id="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email Address">
    <label style="margin: 10px; width:70%" for="requiredby">Required by</label> <br>
    <input style="margin-top: 0px; width: 70%" placeholder="Contact Name" id="requiredby" class="form-control details" name="dueby" type="date" />
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div align="center" class="addsection"></div>
  <button align="center" id="addbutton" style="width: 50%; margin-top: 10px" class="btn btn-primary   ">Add a product</button>
  <button align="center" id="removeprod" style="width: 50%; margin-top: 10px" class="btn btn-danger   ">Re-Enter Products</button>
  <div>
    <button id="serialize" style="width: 50%; margin-top: 10px" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

If anyone can see where I went wrong this would be greatly appreciated.:)

Cheers,

Comment: oh btw everything else works including the append. its just the for loop creating an array from the input data that doesnt work.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: sure thing https://jsfiddle.net/se0j11pe/5/

Comment: Thank you, I have used it to create an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sam Onela pointed out, one of the problems was that you went until `id.length` with your cycle instead of `id`.

However, that was not the only bug. Another problem was that you start the cycle from 0 never reaching `id`, while `id` values start from 1. You can fix this by changing the cycle to

```
  for (i = 1; i <= id; i++) {
```

This makes your script almost correct, however, you still have some typos, like

Instead of

```
id="orientation"' + id + '"
```

use

```
id="orientation' + id + '"
```

and also you use selectors like `"input#yourid" + id` in case when the tag is not an `input`, but something else, like a `select` or a `textarea`. Full solution:

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form align="center" method="post" action="">
  <!--action=kidigital.php-->
  <div align="center">
    <input style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" type="text" class="form-control details" id="contactname" name="Contactname" placeholder="Contact Name">
    <input style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" type="text" class="form-control details" id="companyname" name="Companyname" placeholder="Company Name">
    <input style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" type="text" class="form-control details" id="address" name="Address" placeholder="Address">
    <input style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" type="number" class="form-control details" id="contactnumber" name="Contactnumber" placeholder="Contact Number">
    <input style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" type="email" class="form-control details" id="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email Address">
    <label style="margin: 10px; width:70%" for="requiredby">Required by</label> <br>
    <input style="margin-top: 0px; width: 70%" placeholder="Contact Name" id="requiredby" class="form-control details" name="dueby" type="date" />
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div align="center" class="addsection"></div>
  <button align="center" id="addbutton" style="width: 50%; margin-top: 10px" class="btn btn-primary   ">Add a product</button>
  <button align="center" id="removeprod" style="width: 50%; margin-top: 10px" class="btn btn-danger   ">Re-Enter Products</button>
  <div>
    <button id="serialize" style="width: 50%; margin-top: 10px" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
var id = 0;
$('#addbutton').click(function() {
  id++;
  var large = '<div class="contentprint" id="section[' + id + ']"><h2>Product:' + id + '</h2>' +
    '<p class="form-check has-success"><label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" style="user-select: none" class="form-check-input btn btn-success" id="logo' + id + '" value="yes">Custom Logo</label></p><p style="font-size: 10px; margin: 0px">*Please provide in high resolution .png format(upon confirmation of quote)</p><p style="font-size: 10px; margin: 0px">*$50 set up fee for new logos on orders up to 10 plates</p>' +
    '<input id="quantity' + id + '" style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" type="number" class="form-control quanty" placeholder="Enter Quantity">' +
    '<select  id="orientation' + id + '" style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" class="ori" ><option disabled selected value> -- Orientation --</option> <option value="clipsal_2000_series">Horizontal</option><option value="clipsal_2000_series">Vertical</option></select>' +
    '<select class="plate" id="plate' + id + '" style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" ><option disabled selected value> -- Wall Plate --</option><option value="clipsal_2000_series">Clipsal 2000 series</option><option value="clipsal_classic_2000_series">Clipsal classic 200 series</option><option value="clipsal_standard_31_series">Clipsal standard 31 series</option><option value="other">Other(list in comments)</option></select>' +
    '<select class="color" id="colour' + id + '" style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" > <option disabled selected value> -- Colour --</option> <option value="white">White</option> <option value="black">Black</option> <option value="other">Other(list in comments)</option></select>' +
    '<p style="margin-top:10px; width:100%">Choose your connections</p>' +
    ' <select class="1consel" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="1connection' + id + '"><option disabled selected value> -- Connection 1 --</option> <option> HDMI(Tail)</option><option>VGA(Tail)</option><option>Displayport Tail Female to Female</option> <option>FType(TV) 3Ghz Female to Female</option><option>Optical(Tos Link)</option> <option>Data(RJ45 Cat6 Ethernet [Cat5e compatible])</option><option>BNC(Video)</option><option>DVI (Pass through adapter)</option><option>RS232(DB9)(Pass through adapter)</option><option>SVideo(Pass through adapter)</option><optgroup label="USB"><option>A Female to A Female</option> <option>B Female to A Female</option> <option> USB A Female to A Male</option> <option> USB B Male to A Female</option><option>USB B Female to B Male</option> <option>USB Active Extender A Female to A Female</option> </optgroup>  <optgroup label="XLR"><option>Male Gen 3</option><option>Male Gen 4</option><option>Male Gen 5</option><option>Female Gen 3</option><option>Female Gen 4</option><option>Female Gen 5</option></optgroup><optgroup label="RCA Pass though adapters"><option>Audio(Red &amp; White)</option> <option>Composite video(Yellow)</option><option>AV COmbined(RWY)</option></optgroup><option>Component(All RCA RGB) All RCA Pass Throughs</option></select>' +
    ' <select class="2consel" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="2connection' + id + '"><option disabled selected value> -- Connection 2 --</option> <option> HDMI(Tail)</option><option>VGA(Tail)</option><option>Displayport Tail Female to Female</option> <option>FType(TV) 3Ghz Female to Female</option><option>Optical(Tos Link)</option> <option>Data(RJ45 Cat6 Ethernet [Cat5e compatible])</option><option>BNC(Video)</option><option>DVI (Pass through adapter)</option><option>RS232(DB9)(Pass through adapter)</option><option>SVideo(Pass through adapter)</option> <optgroup label="USB"><option>A Female to A Female</option> <option>B Female to A Female</option> <option> USB A Female to A Male</option> <option> USB B Male to A Female</option><option>USB B Female to B Male</option> <option>USB Active Extender A Female to A Female</option> </optgroup>  <optgroup label="XLR"><option>Male Gen 3</option><option>Male Gen 4</option><option>Male Gen 5</option><option>Female Gen 3</option><option>Female Gen 4</option><option>Female Gen 5</option></optgroup><optgroup label="RCA Pass though adapters"><option>Audio(Red &amp; White)</option> <option>Composite video(Yellow)</option><option>AV COmbined(RWY)</option></optgroup><option>Component(All RCA RGB) All RCA Pass Throughs</option></select>' +
    ' <input class="1consellog" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="1wordconnection' + id + '" placeholder="Connection 1 Custom Label(max 15 chars)" type="text" />' +
    ' <input class="2consellog" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="2wordconnection' + id + '" placeholder="Connection 2 Custom Label(max 15 chars)" type="text" />' +
    ' <select class="3consel" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="3connection' + id + '"><option disabled selected value> -- Connection 3 --</option><option> HDMI(Tail)</option><option>VGA(Tail)</option><option>Displayport Tail Female to Female</option> <option>FType(TV) 3Ghz Female to Female</option><option>Optical(Tos Link)</option> <option>Data(RJ45 Cat6 Ethernet [Cat5e compatible])</option><option>BNC(Video)</option><option>DVI (Pass through adapter)</option><option>RS232(DB9)(Pass through adapter)</option><option>SVideo(Pass through adapter)</option>  <optgroup label="USB"><option>A Female to A Female</option> <option>B Female to A Female</option> <option> USB A Female to A Male</option> <option> USB B Male to A Female</option><option>USB B Female to B Male</option> <option>USB Active Extender A Female to A Female</option> </optgroup> <optgroup label="XLR"><option>Male Gen 3</option><option>Male Gen 4</option><option>Male Gen 5</option><option>Female Gen 3</option><option>Female Gen 4</option><option>Female Gen 5</option></optgroup><optgroup label="RCA Pass though adapters"><option>Audio(Red &amp; White)</option> <option>Composite video(Yellow)</option><option>AV COmbined(RWY)</option></optgroup><option>Component(All RCA RGB) All RCA Pass Throughs</option></select>' +
    ' <select class="4consel" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="4connection' + id + '"><option disabled selected value> -- Connection 4 --</option><option> HDMI(Tail)</option><option>VGA(Tail)</option><option>Displayport Tail Female to Female</option> <option>FType(TV) 3Ghz Female to Female</option><option>Optical(Tos Link)</option> <option>Data(RJ45 Cat6 Ethernet [Cat5e compatible])</option><option>BNC(Video)</option><option>DVI (Pass through adapter)</option><option>RS232(DB9)(Pass through adapter)</option><option>SVideo(Pass through adapter)</option> <optgroup label="USB"><option>A Female to A Female</option> <option>B Female to A Female</option> <option> USB A Female to A Male</option> <option> USB B Male to A Female</option><option>USB B Female to B Male</option> <option>USB Active Extender A Female to A Female</option> </optgroup> <optgroup label="XLR"><option>Male Gen 3</option><option>Male Gen 4</option><option>Male Gen 5</option><option>Female Gen 3</option><option>Female Gen 4</option><option>Female Gen 5</option></optgroup><optgroup label="RCA Pass though adapters"><option>Audio(Red &amp; White)</option> <option>Composite video(Yellow)</option><option>AV COmbined(RWY)</option></optgroup><option>Component(All RCA RGB) All RCA Pass Throughs</option></select>' +
    ' <input class="3consellog" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="3wordconnection' + id + '" placeholder="Connection 3 Custom Label(max 15 chars)" type="text" />' +
    ' <input class="4consellog" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="4wordconnection' + id + '" placeholder="Connection 4 Custom Label(max 15 chars)" type="text" />' +
    ' <select class="5consel" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="5connection' + id + '"><option disabled selected value> -- Connection 5 --</option><option> HDMI(Tail)</option><option>VGA(Tail)</option><option>Displayport Tail Female to Female</option> <option>FType(TV) 3Ghz Female to Female</option><option>Optical(Tos Link)</option> <option>Data(RJ45 Cat6 Ethernet [Cat5e compatible])</option><option>BNC(Video)</option><option>DVI (Pass through adapter)</option><option>RS232(DB9)(Pass through adapter)</option><option>SVideo(Pass through adapter)</option> <optgroup label="USB"><option>A Female to A Female</option> <option>B Female to A Female</option> <option> USB A Female to A Male</option> <option> USB B Male to A Female</option><option>USB B Female to B Male</option> <option>USB Active Extender A Female to A Female</option> </optgroup> <optgroup label="XLR"> <option>Male Gen 3</option><option>Male Gen 4</option><option>Male Gen 5</option><option>Female Gen 3</option><option>Female Gen 4</option><option>Female Gen 5</option></optgroup><optgroup label="RCA Pass though adapters"><option>Audio(Red &amp; White)</option> <option>Composite video(Yellow)</option><option>AV COmbined(RWY)</option></optgroup><option>Component(All RCA RGB) All RCA Pass Throughs</option></select>' +
    ' <select class="6consel" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="6connection' + id + '"><option disabled selected value> -- Connection 6 --</option><option> HDMI(Tail)</option><option>VGA(Tail)</option><option>Displayport Tail Female to Female</option> <option>FType(TV) 3Ghz Female to Female</option><option>Optical(Tos Link)</option> <option>Data(RJ45 Cat6 Ethernet [Cat5e compatible])</option><option>BNC(Video)</option><option>DVI (Pass through adapter)</option><option>RS232(DB9)(Pass through adapter)</option><option>SVideo(Pass through adapter)</option> <optgroup label="USB"><option>A Female to A Female</option> <option>B Female to A Female</option> <option> USB A Female to A Male</option> <option> USB B Male to A Female</option><option>USB B Female to B Male</option> <option>USB Active Extender A Female to A Female</option> </optgroup> <optgroup label="XLR"> <option>Male Gen 3</option><option>Male Gen 4</option><option>Male Gen 5</option><option>Female Gen 3</option><option>Female Gen 4</option><option>Female Gen 5</option></optgroup><optgroup label="RCA Pass though adapters"><option>Audio(Red &amp; White)</option> <option>Composite video(Yellow)</option><option>AV COmbined(RWY)</option></optgroup><option>Component(All RCA RGB) All RCA Pass Throughs</option></select>' +
    ' <input class="5consellog" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="5wordconnection' + id + '" placeholder="Connection 5 Custom Label(max 15 chars)" type="text" />' +
    ' <input class="6consellog" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="6wordconnection' + id + '" placeholder="Connection 6 Custom Label(max 15 chars)" type="text" />' +
    '<textarea name="specialinstructions' + id + '" id="specialinstructions' + id + '" style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" class="form-control special" rows="3" placeholder="Special Instructions"></textarea>' +
    '<br><hr><br></div>';

  $('div.addsection').append(large);
  event.preventDefault();
});
$('#removeprod').on('click', function() {
  $('.contentprint').remove();
});
$('#serialize').click(function(event) {
  var entereddata = [];
  var products = [];

  var i;
  //id is the count of the sections
  for (i = 1; i <= id; i++) {

    var indivproduct = [];
    //dont forget logo
    indivproduct.push([$("input#quantity" + i).val(), $("select#orientation" + i).val(), $("select#plate" + i).val(), $("select#colour" + i).val(), $("select#1connection" + i).val(), $("input#1wordconnection" + i).val(), $("select#2connection" + i).val(), $("input#2wordconnection" + i).val(), $("select#3connection" + i).val(), $("input#3wordconnection" + i).val(), $("select#4connection" + i).val(), $("input#4wordconnection" + i).val(), $("select#5connection" + i).val(), $("input#5wordconnection" + i).val(), $("select#6connection" + i).val(), $("input#6wordconnection" + i).val(), $("textarea#specialinstructions" + i).val()]);

    products.push(indivproduct);

  };

  entereddata.push([$("input#contactname").val(), $("input#companyname").val(), $("input#address").val(), $("input#contactnumber").val(), $("input#email").val(), $("input#requiredby").val(), products]);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(entereddata));
  //return false;//don't submit form  

  /*send json data to file
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: {mydata: JSON.stringify(entereddata)},
      url: "index.php",
      success: function(data){
      }
  });
  */
});
```

Comment: omg that fixed everything. we have a new champion. no more errors. thanks again guys. you are my heros.

Comment: @slyk_style you are welcome. If this answer solved your problem, you might want to consider accepting it. This way you will let future visitors know that the problem has been solved, which might be helpful in case of similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `id` is an integer [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) and (unless the prototype has been modified) has no property *length*.

In order to have the *for* loop run while *i* is less than the **value** of *id*, update the *for* loop conditions from:

```
for (i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
```

To

```
for (i = 0; i < id; i++) {
```

For posterity, [Lajos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/436560/lajos-arpad)  pointed out another issue - that the loop starts at 0 and goes until it reaches 1 less than the value of *id*. However, the first input has an *id* attribute of *input#quantity1* because of the location of the incrementer code. There are multiple options to change the code in order to have it work.

1. move the line `i++;` after the code that creates the string of HTML, so the value 0 is used before it gets incremented to 1 (see code snippet below)
2. Start the for loop at 1 instead of 0 (as Lajos mentioned)

   ```
   for (i = 1; i <= id; i++) {
   ```

```js
var id = 0;
$('#addbutton').click(function() {
  var large = '<div class="contentprint" id="section[' + id + ']"><h2>Product:' + id + '</h2>' +
    '<p class="form-check has-success"><label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" style="user-select: none" class="form-check-input btn btn-success" id="logo' + id + '" value="yes">Custom Logo</label></p><p style="font-size: 10px; margin: 0px">*Please provide in high resolution .png format(upon confirmation of quote)</p><p style="font-size: 10px; margin: 0px">*$50 set up fee for new logos on orders up to 10 plates</p>' +
    '<input id="quantity' + id + '" style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" type="number" class="form-control quanty" placeholder="Enter Quantity">' +
    '<select  id="orientation"' + id + '" style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" class="ori" ><option disabled selected value> -- Orientation --</option> <option value="clipsal_2000_series">Horizontal</option><option value="clipsal_2000_series">Vertical</option></select>' +
    '<select class="plate" id="plate"' + id + '" style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" ><option disabled selected value> -- Wall Plate --</option><option value="clipsal_2000_series">Clipsal 2000 series</option><option value="clipsal_classic_2000_series">Clipsal classic 200 series</option><option value="clipsal_standard_31_series">Clipsal standard 31 series</option><option value="other">Other(list in comments)</option></select>' +
    '<select class="color" id="colour"' + id + '" style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" > <option disabled selected value> -- Colour --</option> <option value="white">White</option> <option value="black">Black</option> <option value="other">Other(list in comments)</option></select>' +
    '<p style="margin-top:10px; width:100%">Choose your connections</p>' +
    ' <select class="1consel" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="1connection' + id + '"><option disabled selected value> -- Connection 1 --</option> <option> HDMI(Tail)</option><option>VGA(Tail)</option><option>Displayport Tail Female to Female</option> <option>FType(TV) 3Ghz Female to Female</option><option>Optical(Tos Link)</option> <option>Data(RJ45 Cat6 Ethernet [Cat5e compatible])</option><option>BNC(Video)</option><option>DVI (Pass through adapter)</option><option>RS232(DB9)(Pass through adapter)</option><option>SVideo(Pass through adapter)</option><optgroup label="USB"><option>A Female to A Female</option> <option>B Female to A Female</option> <option> USB A Female to A Male</option> <option> USB B Male to A Female</option><option>USB B Female to B Male</option> <option>USB Active Extender A Female to A Female</option> </optgroup>  <optgroup label="XLR"><option>Male Gen 3</option><option>Male Gen 4</option><option>Male Gen 5</option><option>Female Gen 3</option><option>Female Gen 4</option><option>Female Gen 5</option></optgroup><optgroup label="RCA Pass though adapters"><option>Audio(Red &amp; White)</option> <option>Composite video(Yellow)</option><option>AV COmbined(RWY)</option></optgroup><option>Component(All RCA RGB) All RCA Pass Throughs</option></select>' +
    ' <select class="2consel" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="2connection' + id + '"><option disabled selected value> -- Connection 2 --</option> <option> HDMI(Tail)</option><option>VGA(Tail)</option><option>Displayport Tail Female to Female</option> <option>FType(TV) 3Ghz Female to Female</option><option>Optical(Tos Link)</option> <option>Data(RJ45 Cat6 Ethernet [Cat5e compatible])</option><option>BNC(Video)</option><option>DVI (Pass through adapter)</option><option>RS232(DB9)(Pass through adapter)</option><option>SVideo(Pass through adapter)</option> <optgroup label="USB"><option>A Female to A Female</option> <option>B Female to A Female</option> <option> USB A Female to A Male</option> <option> USB B Male to A Female</option><option>USB B Female to B Male</option> <option>USB Active Extender A Female to A Female</option> </optgroup>  <optgroup label="XLR"><option>Male Gen 3</option><option>Male Gen 4</option><option>Male Gen 5</option><option>Female Gen 3</option><option>Female Gen 4</option><option>Female Gen 5</option></optgroup><optgroup label="RCA Pass though adapters"><option>Audio(Red &amp; White)</option> <option>Composite video(Yellow)</option><option>AV COmbined(RWY)</option></optgroup><option>Component(All RCA RGB) All RCA Pass Throughs</option></select>' +
    ' <input class="1consellog" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="1wordconnection' + id + '" placeholder="Connection 1 Custom Label(max 15 chars)" type="text" />' +
    ' <input class="2consellog" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="2wordconnection' + id + '" placeholder="Connection 2 Custom Label(max 15 chars)" type="text" />' +
    ' <select class="3consel" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="3connection' + id + '"><option disabled selected value> -- Connection 3 --</option><option> HDMI(Tail)</option><option>VGA(Tail)</option><option>Displayport Tail Female to Female</option> <option>FType(TV) 3Ghz Female to Female</option><option>Optical(Tos Link)</option> <option>Data(RJ45 Cat6 Ethernet [Cat5e compatible])</option><option>BNC(Video)</option><option>DVI (Pass through adapter)</option><option>RS232(DB9)(Pass through adapter)</option><option>SVideo(Pass through adapter)</option>  <optgroup label="USB"><option>A Female to A Female</option> <option>B Female to A Female</option> <option> USB A Female to A Male</option> <option> USB B Male to A Female</option><option>USB B Female to B Male</option> <option>USB Active Extender A Female to A Female</option> </optgroup> <optgroup label="XLR"><option>Male Gen 3</option><option>Male Gen 4</option><option>Male Gen 5</option><option>Female Gen 3</option><option>Female Gen 4</option><option>Female Gen 5</option></optgroup><optgroup label="RCA Pass though adapters"><option>Audio(Red &amp; White)</option> <option>Composite video(Yellow)</option><option>AV COmbined(RWY)</option></optgroup><option>Component(All RCA RGB) All RCA Pass Throughs</option></select>' +
    ' <select class="4consel" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="4connection' + id + '"><option disabled selected value> -- Connection 4 --</option><option> HDMI(Tail)</option><option>VGA(Tail)</option><option>Displayport Tail Female to Female</option> <option>FType(TV) 3Ghz Female to Female</option><option>Optical(Tos Link)</option> <option>Data(RJ45 Cat6 Ethernet [Cat5e compatible])</option><option>BNC(Video)</option><option>DVI (Pass through adapter)</option><option>RS232(DB9)(Pass through adapter)</option><option>SVideo(Pass through adapter)</option> <optgroup label="USB"><option>A Female to A Female</option> <option>B Female to A Female</option> <option> USB A Female to A Male</option> <option> USB B Male to A Female</option><option>USB B Female to B Male</option> <option>USB Active Extender A Female to A Female</option> </optgroup> <optgroup label="XLR"><option>Male Gen 3</option><option>Male Gen 4</option><option>Male Gen 5</option><option>Female Gen 3</option><option>Female Gen 4</option><option>Female Gen 5</option></optgroup><optgroup label="RCA Pass though adapters"><option>Audio(Red &amp; White)</option> <option>Composite video(Yellow)</option><option>AV COmbined(RWY)</option></optgroup><option>Component(All RCA RGB) All RCA Pass Throughs</option></select>' +
    ' <input class="3consellog" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="3wordconnection' + id + '" placeholder="Connection 3 Custom Label(max 15 chars)" type="text" />' +
    ' <input class="4consellog" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="4wordconnection' + id + '" placeholder="Connection 4 Custom Label(max 15 chars)" type="text" />' +
    ' <select class="5consel" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="5connection' + id + '"><option disabled selected value> -- Connection 5 --</option><option> HDMI(Tail)</option><option>VGA(Tail)</option><option>Displayport Tail Female to Female</option> <option>FType(TV) 3Ghz Female to Female</option><option>Optical(Tos Link)</option> <option>Data(RJ45 Cat6 Ethernet [Cat5e compatible])</option><option>BNC(Video)</option><option>DVI (Pass through adapter)</option><option>RS232(DB9)(Pass through adapter)</option><option>SVideo(Pass through adapter)</option> <optgroup label="USB"><option>A Female to A Female</option> <option>B Female to A Female</option> <option> USB A Female to A Male</option> <option> USB B Male to A Female</option><option>USB B Female to B Male</option> <option>USB Active Extender A Female to A Female</option> </optgroup> <optgroup label="XLR"> <option>Male Gen 3</option><option>Male Gen 4</option><option>Male Gen 5</option><option>Female Gen 3</option><option>Female Gen 4</option><option>Female Gen 5</option></optgroup><optgroup label="RCA Pass though adapters"><option>Audio(Red &amp; White)</option> <option>Composite video(Yellow)</option><option>AV COmbined(RWY)</option></optgroup><option>Component(All RCA RGB) All RCA Pass Throughs</option></select>' +
    ' <select class="6consel" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="6connection' + id + '"><option disabled selected value> -- Connection 6 --</option><option> HDMI(Tail)</option><option>VGA(Tail)</option><option>Displayport Tail Female to Female</option> <option>FType(TV) 3Ghz Female to Female</option><option>Optical(Tos Link)</option> <option>Data(RJ45 Cat6 Ethernet [Cat5e compatible])</option><option>BNC(Video)</option><option>DVI (Pass through adapter)</option><option>RS232(DB9)(Pass through adapter)</option><option>SVideo(Pass through adapter)</option> <optgroup label="USB"><option>A Female to A Female</option> <option>B Female to A Female</option> <option> USB A Female to A Male</option> <option> USB B Male to A Female</option><option>USB B Female to B Male</option> <option>USB Active Extender A Female to A Female</option> </optgroup> <optgroup label="XLR"> <option>Male Gen 3</option><option>Male Gen 4</option><option>Male Gen 5</option><option>Female Gen 3</option><option>Female Gen 4</option><option>Female Gen 5</option></optgroup><optgroup label="RCA Pass though adapters"><option>Audio(Red &amp; White)</option> <option>Composite video(Yellow)</option><option>AV COmbined(RWY)</option></optgroup><option>Component(All RCA RGB) All RCA Pass Throughs</option></select>' +
    ' <input class="5consellog" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="5wordconnection' + id + '" placeholder="Connection 5 Custom Label(max 15 chars)" type="text" />' +
    ' <input class="6consellog" style="margin-top:10px; width:35%" id="6wordconnection' + id + '" placeholder="Connection 6 Custom Label(max 15 chars)" type="text" />' +
    '<textarea name="specialinstructions"' + id + '" style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" class="form-control special" rows="3" placeholder="Special Instructions"></textarea>' +
    '<br><hr><br></div>';

  id++;
  $('div.addsection').append(large);
  event.preventDefault();
});
$('#removeprod').on('click', function() {
  $('.contentprint').remove();
});
$('#serialize').click(function() {
  var entereddata = [];
  var products = [];

  var i;
  //id is the count of the sections
  for (i = 0; i < id; i++) {

    var indivproduct = [];
    //dont forget logo
    indivproduct.push([$("input#quantity" + i).val(), $("input#orientation" + i).val(), $("input#plate" + i).val(), $("input#colour" + i).val(), $("input#1connection" + i).val(), $("input#1wordconnection" + i).val(), $("input#2connection" + i).val(), $("input#2wordconnection" + i).val(), $("input#3connection" + i).val(), $("input#3wordconnection" + i).val(), $("input#4connection" + i).val(), $("input#4wordconnection" + i).val(), $("input#5connection" + i).val(), $("input#5wordconnection" + i).val(), $("input#6connection" + i).val(), $("input#6wordconnection" + i).val(), $("input#specialinstructions" + i).val()]);

    products.push(indivproduct);

  };

  entereddata.push([$("input#contactname").val(), $("input#companyname").val(), $("input#address").val(), $("input#contactnumber").val(), $("input#email").val(), $("input#requiredby").val(), products]);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(entereddata));
  return false;//don't submit form  

  /*send json data to file
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: {mydata: JSON.stringify(entereddata)},
      url: "index.php",
      success: function(data){
      }
  });
  */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form align="center" method="post" action="">
  <!--action=kidigital.php-->
  <div align="center">
    <input style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" type="text" class="form-control details" id="contactname" name="Contactname" placeholder="Contact Name">
    <input style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" type="text" class="form-control details" id="companyname" name="Companyname" placeholder="Company Name">
    <input style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" type="text" class="form-control details" id="address" name="Address" placeholder="Address">
    <input style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" type="number" class="form-control details" id="contactnumber" name="Contactnumber" placeholder="Contact Number">
    <input style="margin-top:10px; width:70%" type="email" class="form-control details" id="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email Address">
    <label style="margin: 10px; width:70%" for="requiredby">Required by</label> <br>
    <input style="margin-top: 0px; width: 70%" placeholder="Contact Name" id="requiredby" class="form-control details" name="dueby" type="date" />
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div align="center" class="addsection"></div>
  <button align="center" id="addbutton" style="width: 50%; margin-top: 10px" class="btn btn-primary   ">Add a product</button>
  <button align="center" id="removeprod" style="width: 50%; margin-top: 10px" class="btn btn-danger   ">Re-Enter Products</button>
  <div>
    <button id="serialize" style="width: 50%; margin-top: 10px" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: omg sam your amazing. but for some reason it shows all values as null. is that because $("input#quantity" + i).val() is in correct?

Comment: @slyk_style yes - I see Lajos already explained about the issue with the initial value of the loop variable; thanks Lajos!